# How to instantiate any view first inside a container page view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

So I have a container view which holds 3 view controllers. When I launch the app I believe all 3 views instantiates. The issue I am having is this app is deep linking to a 4th view which plays a video using AVPlayer. How would you go about "skipping" or instantiating the "previous" view controllers to launch this view controller with AVPLayer?

Sorry if the questions is a bit confusing!

Comment: what are you using container view or pageviewcontroller.??

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate your 4th view controller directly with following code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```